# Does an increasing-and-then-decreasing validation loss mean the model is overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm currently using an EEGNet model to train on baseline corrected EEG data (containing 64 channels sampled at 512 Hz) to classify three mental states hence it's a 3 class classification problem. The EEG data is as 6 files, (A, B, C, D, E and F, where each File contains the potentials of recorded EEG signals (which are 5 minutes long) across 64 channels). Now I'm training the model on files (A, B, C with each file corresponding to a different class label out of the 3 classes), same applies for the files D, E, F, which is taken as validation data. But during training, I find the validation loss to increase first, and then steeply dip down at 100th epoch from where the loss continues decreasing slowly. So should I be happy that my model is generalising well on validation data after 100th epoch or should I consider it overfits for increasing the validation loss, during the first 100 epochs? Or is there anything that I'm not doing right?

The hyperparameters used in my model training are:

- Optimizer : Adam
- Learning rate : 1e-3
- Training size : 1440
- Validation size : 360
- Train Batch Size : 256
- Validation Batch Size : 16
- Epochs : 800

[image: training and validation loss curves]

Comment: happened to me with a heteroskedasticity estimation model... at the beginning the model used only $\sigma$ to justify the predictions, which lead to the peak in validation, and after a while started to optimize the $\mu$, which decreased the validation loss... and the model was super basic, so for sure not overfitting

Comment: I would generally ignore what happens in the first few epochs. The random weight initialisation dominates the results of the early epochs, so it takes a bit of training before the model shows reliable trends. However, you could try varying the learning rate and/or training batch size to see if that changes the learning curves.